# JavaScript: Scroll an iframe until the div with focus appears in the center of the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a scrollable iframe.  A function is called which is passed an ID of a div (a text message bubble) to focus on.  It works but when focusing on the item it always appears at the very top of the iframe.  So the user has to scroll up a little bit to see the message that the user is replying to.  I'd like for the function to focus on the message but have it appear in the very center of iframe.  I believe the problem lies in me trying to use...

`iframe.contentWindow.location.hash`

in combination with...

`iframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(0,400);`

I having trouble thinking of a solution to this.  I'm thinking maybe get the y-coord of the item in question and `scrollTo` it's y-coord + half the height of the iframe.  But haven't had luck yet.  Here is a jsfiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/df09shon/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Basically I had to do away with the `iframe.contentWindow.location.hash` and instead just grab the bubble's y-coord then scrollTo that position minus half the height of the iframe.  Here it is... http://jsfiddle.net/df09shon/8/

The key parts are this...

```
var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
//console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);
iframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(0,rect.top-iframe.clientHeight / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution working on Firefox (I can't test on Internet Explorer):
http://jsfiddle.net/df09shon/4/

I just put your *scrollTo()* in a *window.setTimeout()*. In that case, I'm sure to do the scroll after the *location.hash*.

```
window.setTimeout(
    function() {
        iframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(
            0, iframe.contentWindow.scrollY - iframe.clientHeight / 2);
    }
);
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work for me. My solution still seems to work in all browsers.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    function goToMsg(id){
      var elem = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById(id);
      iframe.contentWindow.location.hash = id;
      $("html, body")
      .animate({scrollTop:$( elem ).offset().top}, 250, function() {        
        $(elem).fadeIn(200).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200)
        .fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200)
        .fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200);
      })
    //iframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(100,100);
    }
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/df09shon/6/

Comment: Thanks but not quite what I'm looking for.  That moves the bubble out of its position in the conversation and on top of another bubble.  I want the bubble to stay where it is, just make the iframe scroll to it so that it appears in the middle of the iframe, not at the top.

Comment: That still doesn't work for me.  I'm using the latest version of Chrome.